# Need a code structure advice for nodemcu http calls

Tags: lua, nodemcu

What i want to achive?

1. Make http call to get an auth token
2. read some sensor data
3. use auth token to send sensor data via http
4. put node into deep sleep

Some limitation of the nodemcu firmware (master) are:

1. You can not make synchronous http request
2. the callback function of the second http.post won't be called
3. you can not return the value of the callback function and even so (see 2.)

these limitation basically stop me from doing what i try to achive.

Here is a pseudo code example i wrote, this will not work because of limitation 2.

From the documentation :

> It is not possible to execute concurrent HTTP requests using this module.

```
    state={[0]="init", [1]="init"}

    http.post(url, params, function(res){
        state[0]=finished;
        sleep()
    });

    http.post(url, params, function(res){
        //wont be called due fw limitations
        state[1]=finished;
        sleep()
    });

    function sleep()
    {
        if(canWeSleep())
        {
            //run dsleep
        }
    }


    function canWeSleep()
    {
        for k, v in pairs(state) do
            if state[k]=="init" then
                print(v)
                return false
            end
        end
        return true;

    }
```

Another approach i tried was to return the callback function, but since the http module does not support it nor synchronous connection this will not work either..

```
function auth(user, pass)
    return http.post('https://home.io.moving-bytes.at/api/v1/login',
      'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n',
      'username='..user..'&password='..pass,
      function(code, data)
      if (code < 0) then  
         print("HTTP request failed")
      else
         t = sjson.decode(data)
         token= t.token
         return token
      end
    end) 

end

function post(key, val, token)

    return http.post('https://home.io.moving-bytes.at/api/',
      'Authorization: Bearer '..token..'\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n',

      'key='..key..'&val='..val,
      function(code, data)
      if (code < 0) then  
         print("HTTP request failed")
      else
        print(data)
      end
    end)

end 

local token=auth("user", "pass");
post("key", 123, token)
```

my latest approach was to use a callback function which did not work either...

```
local token=nil

function send_data(key, val, callback)
    callback()
    print("send data")
    print("key "..key)
    print("token in send data"..token)
    http.post('http://home.io.moving-bytes.at/api/sensors/data',
      'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n',
      'sensor_id=5&key='..key..'&value='..val,
      function(code, data)
      print("callback called")
      if (code < 0) then
         print("HTTP request failed")
         print("key: "..key)
         print("val: "..val)
      else
         print(code, data)
      end
    end)

end


function auth(user, pass)
    print("auth")
    print("user "..user);
    print("pass "..pass);
    http.post('https://home.io.moving-bytes.at/api/v1/login',
      'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n',
      'username='..user..'&password='..pass,
      function(code, data)
      if (code < 0) then
         print("HTTP request failed")
      else
         t = sjson.decode(data)
         token= t.token
         print("token"..token)
      end
    end)

end


send_data("distance", 3, auth("user", "passs"));
```

Please for god sake i wasted way to much time to make two simple http calls....
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your first code looks like a correct way to do.  What does exactly happen when you run it?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff the trouble is the firmware, only the first http.post callback will be called. From my server logs i can say the second http.post will be processed, but the callback function will never be called.

Comment: Untested: `auth("user", "passs")`, then in this function's HTTP callback call `node.task.post(send_data(token))` (unrelated to _HTTP_ post).

Comment: so when i like to send three or more key/val paris the code would look something like this: node.task.post(send_data("key", "val" token,send_data("key", "val" token,send_data("key", "val" token))))   is there not a cleaner solution for such a standard workflow?